# Is DotNetNuke CMS W3C Standards compliant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

**My questions is:**
Whether DotNetNuke is W3C compliant for the code it generates?

Mostly articles that I have read are bit outdated (and I'm a newbie too) so I'm unable to decide.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is probably better place somewhere for this question. Normally SO is not a place for urgent help, nor for deciding if particular framework/toolset works for you...

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Latest version of DotNetNuke 7.x is NOT standard compliant. If you go to http://validator.w3.org/ and add www.dotnetnuke.com you will notice some errors. They are minor and fixable errors. Most of the code is standard compliant but not all.

Comment: You really shouldn't compare DotNetNuke.com to DotNetNuke the product. DNN can be standards compliant, but it is very easy as a content editor to make a site NOT compliant

Comment: I am sorry if that sounds rude, I love dotnetnuke as much as you love it. But create a brand new install of dotnetnuke and validate it against the url above to try what I answer over here.